# Можно ли данные 2ух столбцов в combobox? у меня получается только вывод данных из 1 столбца

Tags: c#, sql-server

SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("****");

```
         con.Open();

        string SqlDataPull = ("Select  iKodSotr,sFamSotr FROM dbo.tSotrudnik");
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(SqlDataPull,con);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        while (dr.Read())
        {
            SqlDataPull = dr[0].ToString();
            cmbMOLFORMreg.Items.Add(SqlDataPull);

        }
```

и как потом получить выбранное значение раздельно

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Либо создавайте класс, описывающий нужные Вам данные, либо используйте DataTable. Затем прописывайте DisplayMember и ValueMember. Например так (не знаю каких типов поля, поэтому делаю string):

```
class MyClass
{
    public string iKodSotr {get; set;}
    public string sFamSotr {get; set;}
}

...

var data = new List<MyClass>();
while (dr.Read())
{
    var mc = new MyClass
                 {
                       iKodSotr = dr[0].ToString(),
                       sFamSotr = dr[1].ToString()
                 };
}
dr.Close();
cmbMOLFORMreg.DataSource = data;
cmbMOLFORMreg.DisplayMember = "iKodSotr"; // То, что будет отображаться пользователю
cmbMOLFORMreg.ValueMember = "sFamSotr"; // То, что будет в SelectedValue
```

Достать экземпляр можно будет так:

```
var value = (MyClass)cmbMOLFORMreg.SelectedItem;
```

и работать уже со всем объектом.
При работе в DataTable это будет выглядеть примерно так:

```
// Получение DataReader'a
...

var dt = new DataTable();
dt.Load(dr);
dr.Close();
cmbMOLFORMreg.DataSource = dt;
cmbMOLFORMreg.DisplayMember = "iKodSotr"; // То, что будет отображаться пользователю
cmbMOLFORMreg.ValueMember = "sFamSotr"; // То, что будет в SelectedValue
```

Но, думаю, использовать для таких целей DataTable не совсем хорошо, но проще, т.к. не надо каждый раз описывать класс. Хотя могу ошибаться.

Comment: Наприме, изменить запрос на "Select  iKodSotr + sFamSotr FROM dbo.tSotrudnik"